# А где достать aarch64 ассемблер?

Tags: linux, ассемблер, arm

Ну, сколько же в интернете можно найти инфы по NASM, MASM, FASM. Но все это x86/amd64 ассемблеры. А где взять aarch64 ассемблер? Ну или хотя бы скомпилировать NASM в aarch64? Потому что так-то NASM и yasm даже в Termux собираются без проблем, да только на выходе x86 бинарники.

Comment: Ну как минимум gnu as (gas) точно должен уметь. Или нет?

Comment: ну хз, у меня оно не компилирует. Похоже, что только под x86, хотя мб это я что-то не так делаю...

Comment: Если ругаться, то точно не будет. Nasm может только x86/64. Fasm вроде тоже

Comment: а где взять тогда AARCH64 ассемблер? Ну или хотя бы необходимую обёртку из C или C++

Comment: Ещё раз пишу gnu as. Доступен практически на любом линуксе

Comment: `apt show gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu` оно?

Comment: это компилятор. А мне собственно надо ассемблер: ну там How-To, все такое...